# Bind ListView to ListProperty

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

Is it possible in tornadoFX to bind a ListView to a ListProperty?

I have a ViewModel like follows:

```
class MyVm: ItemViewModel<Item>() {
    val stringProperty = bind { item?.myString?.toProperty() }
}

class MyView: View() {
    ...
    init {
        with (root) {
            label(myVm.stringProperty)
        }
    }
}
```

if the item changes with `vm.item = Item(...)`  the stringProperty will be updated accordingly, which will update all bound labels etc...

Now I want to do the same with a ListView:

```
class MyVm: ItemViewModel<Item>() {
    val listProperty = bind { item?.myList?.toProperty() }
}

class MyView: View() {
    ...
    init {
        with (root) {
            listview {
                items = myVm.listProperty
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case the compiler complains that listview.items expects an `ObservableList` instead of a `ListProperty`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your binding as a ListProperty and pass the listProperty to the listview builder:

`val listProperty = bind(Item::myList) as ListProperty<YourType>`

..

`listview(myVm.listProperty)`

Comment: Perfect. I didn´t realize that the listview function parameter takes a listProperty. So I tried to assign to items.