# Bind ItemViewModel to domain class list

Tags: tornadofx

I have a Rulebook that contains Rules:

```
class Rulebook(val rules:MutableList<Rule>)
```

I have an ItemViewModel for it, as it's used in a multiply-nested selection UI.

```
class RulebookModel : ItemViewModel<Rulebook> {
    val rulesProperty = bind // ... here's my problem
}
```

What is the correct binding to be able to initialize a tableview with the property?

A naive bind yields the wrong type:

```
val rulesProperty = bind(Rulebook::rules)
```

has type `Property<MutableList<Rule>>`, which tableview() doesn't take.

From another answer here I got [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260206/tornadofx-bind-listview-to-listproperty)

```
val rulesProperty = bind(Rulebook::rules) as ListProperty<Rule>
```

This yields the correct type, so we get through compilation, but at runtime I get this:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to javafx.collections.ObservableList

Note: The `RulebookModel` does start life without an item in it yet. I've seen `ArrayLists` come from empty list factory calls before. Is that possibly my actual problem?

What is the correct way to perform this binding?

Answer (score 0):

Your model needs to have a SimpleListProperty to bind into an itemViewModel
Here is some sample code for how to write the classes and a table view:

```
data class rule(val name: String, val def: String)
class RuleBookModel{
  val rulesProperty = SimpleListProperty<rule>()
  var rules by rulesProperty
}
class RuleBookViewModel: ItemViewModel<RuleBookModel>() {
  val rules = bind(ruleBook::rulesProperty)
}

class TestView : View("Test View") {
  val myRuleBook: RuleBookViewModel by inject()
  init {
      // adding a rule so the table doesn't look lonely
      myRuleBook.rules.value.add(rule("test", "fuga"))
  }
  val name = textfield()
  val definition = textfield()
  override val root = vbox{
    hbox {
       label("Name")
       add(name)
    }
    hbox {
       label("Definition")
       add(definition)
    }
    button("Add a rule").action{
        myRuleBook.rules.value.add(rule(name.text, definition.text))
    }
    tableview(myRuleBook.rules) {
        column("name", rule::name)
        column("def", rule::def)
    }
  }
}
```